# Flags to create mutual friends?

Tags: 7, views, flags, users

I'm running a D7 system where users follow each other by using a 'follow' flag and then on user profile I've added a view to show all the users followed by a 'logged-in-user'.

What I'm struggling with is how do I generate a list of users who are followed by the friends of 'logged-in' user.

something like facebook 'mutual friends' functionality so 'logged-in' user get a list of users followed by the users he/she following.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using [Flag Friend](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag_friend) module

> Flag Friend aims to be a lightweight friending module utilizing the
>   excellent Flag module's API.

**Or**

[Flag Follow](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag_follow)

> This is a simple module which allows a user to view Heartbeat
>   activities of his favorites/followed users. A user can add another
>   user to his favorites list by just click on a 'Follow' button. It
>   requires no approval to add a user to your favorites list.

**or**

You can do this by using [Follow](https://www.drupal.org/project/follow) module.

> Follow adds sitewide and per user links that link to various social
>   networking sites. The links reside in two blocks. The Follow Site
>   block lists all the links for the site itself, and by default is
>   visible on all pages. The Follow User block lists all the follow links
>   for the user and is visible only on user profile pages.

Comment: thanks for your prompt response but I cannot change the way flags/flag working at the moment as it would cause problems in messaging and notifications I'm running. I've to use the existing flag 'follow' to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Have you try Flag Follow ?

Comment: What I'm looking for is a list of users followed by my friends, again - something like 'would you like to add user X' 'User-X has 3 Mutual friends with 'you' '

Comment: I'll give 'Flag-follow' a run and will update you @NishantP to how it went

Comment: Ok sure. I hope your issue might be solved.